# Which one is correct: "I live IN this street" or "I live ON this street"?

Tags: prepositions, usage, in-on-at

Good afternoon, everyone!

Which one is correct:

1. I live ***in*** this street
2. I live ***on*** this street

I would like to know which one is correct or whether both of them are possible in standard English. If they are both possible, which one is more common in British English?

I know that we usually say: "*I live **on** Fennel Street*" (on+street name) and "*I live **at** 10 Fennel Street*" (at+house number), but I would like to know which preposition should be used preceding the determiner "this" and/or when we are pointing at the street where we live.

Comment: No, it doesn't; sorry. I know the difference between "I live on the street" (=homeless) and "I live in the street" (=here). My question is more related to the use of different prepositions when preceding a specific demostrative ("this").

Comment: I live on this street. For sure.

Comment: @Lambie [Some Brits say "in X Street" where Americans would say "on."](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/54251/on-an-american-street-but-in-a-british-one-do-the-twain-ever-meet)

Comment: In fact, I think most Brits do!

Comment: Why do you think "live in this street" might be different from "live in Main street"?

Comment: Yes, I live in X street. With the name of the street. Sure. I saw him in the High Street. Sure. (All BrE) However, I live in this street, could be ambiguous, if indeed you are living on the street. Of course, in **general** AmE=on//BrE=in. @TypeIA It is not some Brits, it is most Brits.

Comment: @KateBunting Am British, have never heard anyone from any part of the country say `In this street`.

Comment: @Lambie Literally never heard anyone say `In this street`. Also the linked post from TypeIA is referring to being in the street, i.e outside. `Live in the street` sounds like they are homeless.

Comment: @User112638726 How about the headline here: https://www.telegraph.co.uk/property/buy/for-sale-harry-potters-home-in-privet-drive-complete-with-cupboa/ It uses "in Privet Drive" instead of AmE "on Privet Drive"

Comment: @d_b possibly regional then? I see the writer is from London, maybe Northern/Southern differences

Comment: @user112638726 You are misreading what I said: in x street = UK, on x street=US but if you don't use the name of the street, live on a street. He lives on a beautiful street (UK and US). I never said: live in this street, unless it were to mean homeless. See live on a beautiful street: https://www.standard.co.uk/comment/letters/es-views-it-s-a-nowin-situation-for-the-police-over-knife-crime-a3774631.html

Answer (score 0):

In US English, we say, "I live on this street."

If a person is homeless, we say "He lives on the street" or "He lives on the streets".

Note the subtle difference in wording: "He lives on THE street" means he's homeless. "He lives on THIS street" or "He lives on Maple Street" tells us his address. If a homeless person sleeps on the sidewalk on Maple Street, you could say, "He lives on Maple Street", just like you would say about someone who lives in a mansion on that street. "He lives on this street" does not, of itself, tell us whether the person lives in a mansion or the gutter. Really, any more than saying, "He lives in Boston" tells us the nature of his living conditions.

If in British English people say "He lives IN Maple Street" ... sorry, I'm not familiar with that difference between the regional dialects.

Answer (score -1):

I am so confused because according to Cambridge Dictionary:

> **Live "on" the streets** (or "on the street", AmE):
>   To be homeless.

I have also had time to look it up on the book Practical English Usage by Swan and this is what I have found:

> **We generally use "at" to talk about addresses:**
>   *She lives **at** 73 Albert Street.*
>   
>  
>   
>   **We use "in"** (AmE "on") **if we just give the name of the address:**
>   *She lives in Albert Street (BrE)*
>   *She lives on Albert Street (AmE)*
>   
>   **We use "on" for the number of the floor:**
>   
> *She lives in a flat on the third floor.*

Since there seems to be no agreement among native speakers of English, I have come to the conclusion that the preposition depends on the variety of English, although "in" is the standard form for British English and "on" for American English.